# Assign error statement to variable in R

Tags: r, error-handling

My doubt is to assign an error statement to variable or an object in R.
e.g. suppose i am executing statement which is gonna throw an error, i want to save that error statement somewhere so that later i can debug the code. e.g.:

```
x*3   #faulty statement
Error: object 'x' not found  # error thrown because x dont exist
```

but is it possible to save this error statement "object 'x' not found" to variable or to text file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `try` or `tryCatch`.  An example with `try`:

```
res <- try(x * 3)  # if `x * 3` throws and error, `res` will be an error object
if(inherits(res, "try-error")) {          # error happened
  print(conditionMessage(attr(res, "condition")))  # the error message
}
```

Produces:

```
[1] "object 'x' not found"
```

Of course, we could store `res` instead of printing the error message.  If you don't want the error to produce a message when it actually happens, use `try(..., silent=TRUE)` which will completely suppress the message (though you can always access it from the `res` object if you so wish).